# Catching return value from Tcl in batch

Tags: batch-file, return, tcl

This is my Tcl script

```
return 2
```

It is doing nothing, but just returning value 2. Now my batch script call this tcl file called foo.

```
tclsh foo.tcl
```

The return value can change from time to time and I need to get this value in the batch file. Is thr a way to do that. I am new to batch commands, so I dont have much idea about this. I tried if-else loop, but it gives syntax error. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an external caller of Tcl to see a result code, you need `exit` and not `return`:

```
# In Tcl
exit 2
```

Then your caller can use the exit code handling built into it to detect. For example with bash (and most other Unix shells):

```
# Not Tcl, but rather bash
tclsh foo.tcl
echo "exit code was $?"
```

On Windows, I think it's something to do with `ERRORLEVEL` but it's a long time since I used that platform for that sort of thing. I just remember it being annoying…

Comment: That doesnt help donal. Because whatever exit value you choose, it will always return to ERRORLEVEL 1

Comment: @UnderDog You are aware that [`IF ERRORLEVEL x` tests if the exit code is _at least_ `x`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

It appears `%ERRORLEVEL%` **is** what you want:

```
C:\Users\glennj>tclsh
% exit 3

C:\Users\glennj>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
3
```

Comment: Excellent! All i needed